# java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][SparkJDBCDriver](500151) Error setting/closing session: Open Session Error

Tags: python-3.x, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, simba

i want to connect sparksql with jdbc in code

```
   import jaydebeapi

    conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.simba.spark.jdbc41.Driver',"jdbc:spark://localhost:10000/default;AuthMech=3;SSL=0",{'user': 'spark', 'password': "di6'gnr"},'/hdfs/dev/scripts/pyspark/drivers/SparkJDBC41.jar',)
    curs = conn.cursor()

    curs.execute("select * from CUSTOMER")
    curs.fetchall()

    curs.close()
    conn.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik1Rt.png)

Comment: can you tell us more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have table customer create by pyspark  schemaPeople.createOrReplaceTempView("customer") and i want to query it by jdbc

Comment: spark service don't have aucthencation sercurity